# Fluxbox: User added menu entries don't run / execute or open

Tags: freebsd, fluxbox

On **FreeBSD 13**, I installed **Fluxbox** and added two menu entries to the *Fluxbox menu*:

```
[exec] (Lazarus IDE) {lazarus}
[exec] (Set Resolution) {xrandr -s 1680x1050}
```

Both of these show up on the *Fluxbox menu*, but do nothing when clicked. I have tried giving the full path of the program too:

```
[exec] (Lazarus IDE) {/usr/local/bin/lazarus}
```

That also doesn't work. The commands however work fine through `Xterm` in Fluxbox.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Update**:

When I run `lazarus` from the terminal, I noticed the output states:

```
TLazarusManager.Run starting /home/s/.lazarus/bin/lazarus ...
```

But even that path doesn't execute from FluxBox menu.

Comment: On FreeBSD 13 with Fluxbox, `{lazarus}` work for me. It open Lazarus IDE with the Fluxbox menu. Maybe you can try `{/usr/local/share/lazarus-2.0.10/startlazarus --pcp=~/.lazarus_test}`. Replacing with your Lazarus version and your [Primary Config Path - pcp=](https://wiki.freepascal.org/pcp). Or lazarus in place of startlazarus. `xrandr` didn't work for me either.

Comment: @Gounou No, I tried everything you suggested but Lazarus still doesn't open from the menu.